# Solving a Recurrence Relation: T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n/2)+n

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, recurrence

**Solve: T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n/2)+n**.

I tried solving this using recursion trees.There are two branches `T(n-1)` and `T(n/2)` respectively. `T(n-1)` will go to a higher depth. So we get `O(2^n)`. Is this idea correct?

Comment: @hevi this is an algorithms question, not a math question. As such it is ok to post here, though http://cs.stackexchange.com/ might be just a tiny bit better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very strange recurrence for a CS class. This is because from one point of view: `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n/2) + n` is bigger than `T(n) = T(n-1) + n` which is O(n^2).

But from another point of view, the **[functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_equation) has an exact solution**: `T(n) = -2(n + 2)`. You can easily see that this is the exact solution by substituting it back to the equation: `-2(n + 2) = -2(n + 1) + -(n + 2) + n`. I am not sure whether this is the only solution.

Here is how I got it: `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n/2) + n`. Because you calculate things for very big `n`, than `n-1` is almost the same as `n`. So you can rewrite it as `T(n) = T(n) + T(n/2) + n` which is `T(n/2) + n = 0`, which is equal to `T(n) = - 2n`, so it is linear. This was counter intuitive to me (the minus sign here), but armed with this solution, I tried `T(n) = -2n + a` and found the value of a.

Comment: O(n) is contained in O(2^n), so his idea could still be correct.  But you can only say T(n)-T(n-1)=o(n) by assuming that T(n)=o(n^2) before you've found an actual solution.

Comment: what is computational meaning of `T(n) = -2n` ? Generally when I say `T(n) = n` then it means, an algorithm with such recurrence relation will perform exactly `n` basic steps (given input `n`) before coming to halt. Now what does `T(n) = -2n` mean?

Comment: I am quite sure that `T(n) = T(n-1)+θ(n) = O(n^2)` and `T(n) = T(n/k)+θ(n) = O(n)`. So I dont believe `T(n) = T(n/2)+T(n-1)+θ(n)` will be `O(n^2)` and has to have higher order than that. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/518859/336409) proves its `O(n^(log n))`. So I guess the answer is incorrect. Can you check?

Comment: @anir. This recursion is very strange. Because from one point of view I clearly see why the solution O(n^2) is reasonable, but at the same point of time, the functional equation has an exact solution: T(n) = -2n - 4.Will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are right. The recurrence relation will always split into two parts, namely T(n-1) and T(n/2). Looking at these two, it is clear that n-1 decreases in value slower than n/2, or in other words, you will have more branches from the n-1 portion of the tree. Despite this, when considering big-o, it is useful to just consider the 'worst-case' scenario, which in this case is that both sides of the tree decreases by n-1 (since this decreases more slowly and you would need to have more branches). In all, you would need to split the relation into two a total of n times, hence you are right to say O(2^n).

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct, but you give away far too much.  (For example, it is also correct to say that `2x^3+4=O(2^n)`, but that’s not as informative as `2x^3+4=O(x^3)`.)

The first thing we want to do is get rid of the inhomogeneous term `n`.  This suggests that we may look for a solution of the form `T(n)=an+b`.  Substituting that in, we find:

```
an+b = a(n-1)+b + an/2+b + n
```

which reduces to

```
0 = (a/2+1)n + (b-a)
```

implying that `a=-2` and `b=a=-2`.  Therefore, `T(n)=-2n-2` is a solution to the equation.

We now want to find other solutions by subtracting off the solution we’ve already found.  Let’s define `U(n)=T(n)+2n+2`.  Then the equation becomes

```
U(n)-2n-2 = U(n-1)-2(n-1)-2 + U(n/2)-2(n/2)-2 + n
```

which reduces to

```
U(n) = U(n-1) + U(n/2).
```

`U(n)=0` is an obvious solution to this equation, but how do the non-trivial solutions to this equation behave?

Let’s assume that `U(n)∈Θ(n^k)` for some `k>0`, so that `U(n)=cn^k+o(n^k)`.  This makes the equation

```
cn^k+o(n^k) = c(n-1)^k+o((n-1)^k) + c(n/2)^k+o((n/2)^k)
```

Now, `(n-1)^k=n^k+Θ(n^{k-1})`, so that the above becomes

```
cn^k+o(n^k) = cn^k+Θ(cn^{k-1})+o(n^k+Θ(n^{k-1})) + cn^k/2^k+o((n/2)^k)
```

Absorbing the lower order terms and subtracting the common `cn^k`, we arrive at

```
o(n^k) = cn^k/2^k
```

But this is false because the right hand side grows faster than the left.  Therefore, `U(n-1)+U(n/2)` grows faster than `U(n)`, which means that `U(n)` must grow faster than our assumed `Θ(n^k)`.  Since this is true for any `k`, `U(n)` must grow faster than any polynomial.

A good example of something that grows faster than any polynomial is an exponential function.  Consequently, let’s assume that `U(n)∈Θ(c^n)` for some `c>1`, so that `U(n)=ac^n+o(c^n)`.  This makes the equation
ac^n+o(c^n) = ac^{n-1}+o(c^{n-1}) + ac^{n/2}+o(c^{n/2})
Rearranging and using some order of growth math, this becomes

```
c^n = o(c^n)
```

This is false (again) because the left hand side grows faster than the right.  Therefore,
`U(n)` grows faster than `U(n-1)+U(n/2)`, which means that `U(n)` must grow slower than our assumed `Θ(c^n)`.  Since this is true for any `c>1`, `U(n)` must grow more slowly than any exponential.

This puts us into the realm of quasi-polynomials, where `ln U(n)∈O(log^c n)`, and subexponentials, where `ln U(n)∈O(n^ε)`.  Either of these mean that we want to look at `L(n):=ln U(n)`, where the previous paragraphs imply that `L(n)∈ω(ln n)∩o(n)`.  Taking the natural log of our equation, we have

```
ln U(n) = ln( U(n-1) + U(n/2) ) = ln U(n-1) + ln(1+ U(n/2)/U(n-1))
```

or

```
L(n) = L(n-1) + ln( 1 + e^{-L(n-1)+L(n/2)} ) = L(n-1) + e^{-(L(n-1)-L(n/2))} + Θ(e^{-2(L(n-1)-L(n/2))})
```

So everything comes down to: how fast does `L(n-1)-L(n/2)` grow?  We know that `L(n-1)-L(n/2)→∞`, since otherwise `L(n)∈Ω(n)`.  And it’s likely that `L(n)-L(n/2)` will be just as useful, since `L(n)-L(n-1)∈o(1)` is much smaller than `L(n-1)-L(n/2)`.

Unfortunately, this is as far as I’m able to take the problem.  I don’t see a good way to control how fast `L(n)-L(n/2)` grows (and I’ve been staring at this for months).  The only thing I can end with is to quote another answer: “a very strange recursion for a CS class”.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can look at it this way:

`T(n)=2T(n/2)+n < T(n)=T(n−1)+T(n/2)+n < T(n)=2T(n−1)+n`

If we apply the master's theorem, then:

`Θ(n∗logn) < Θ(T(n)) < Θ(2n)`

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n/2) + n` being (**asymptotically**) bigger than `T(n) = T(n-1) + n` only applies for functions which are asymptotically positive. In that case, we have `T = Ω(n^2)`.

Note that `T(n) = -2(n + 2)` is a solution to the functional equation, but it doesn't interest us, since it is not an **asymptotically positive** solution, hence the notations of O don't have meaningful application.

You can also easily check that `T(n) = O(2^n)`. (Refer to yyFred solution, if needed)

If you try using the definition of O for functions of the type `n^a(lgn)^b`, with `a(>=2)` and `b` positive constants, you see that this is not a possible solution too by the Substitution Method.

In fact, the only function that allows a proof with the Substitution Method is exponential, but we know that this recursion doesn't grow as fast as `T(n) = 2T(n-1) + n`, so if `T(n) = O(a^n)`, we can have `a < 2`.

Assume that `T(m) <= c(a^m)`, for some constant c, real and positive. Our hypothesis is that this relation is valid for all m < n. Trying to prove this for n, we get:

`T(n) <= (1/a+1/a^(n/2))c(a^n) + n`

we can get rid of the n easily by changing the hypothesis by a term of lower order. What is important here is that:

```
1/a+1/a^(n/2) <= 1

a^(n/2+1)-a^(n/2)-a >= 0
```

Changing variables:

```
a^(N+1)-a^N-a >= 0
```

We want to find a bond as tight as possible, so we are searching for the lowest `a` possible. The inequality we found above accept solutions of `a` which are pretty close to 1, but is `a` allowed to get arbitrarily close to 1? The answer is no, let `a` be of the form `a = (1+1/N)`. Substituting `a` at the inequality and applying the limit `N -> INF`:

```
e-e-1 >= 0
```

which is a absurd. Hence, the inequality above has some fixed number `N*` as maximum solution, which can be found computationally. A quick Python program allowed me to find that `a < 1+1e-45` (with a little extrapolation), so we can at least be sure that:

```
T(n) = ο((1+1e-45)^n)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are several places in the accepted answer that I don't agree with:

1. The exact solution obtained by assuming `T(n)=-2n+a` should be `T(n) = -2(n+1)` instead of `T(n) = -2(n+2)`.
2. 

> T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n/2) + n is bigger than T(n) = T(n-1) + n

It doesn't make sense to compare them in this way because the `T(n)`'s in these two recurrences are not the same.

If we use the tree method, let's assume the total additional work done (row sum) of level `i` (0-indexed) is `S(i)`. By observing the first few levels, it can be known that `S(i)=3/2*S(i-1)+2^(i-1)` and `S(0)=n`. Solve this recurrence using substitution and we have `S(i)=(3/2)^i*n-2^(i+1)+3*(3/2)^(i-1)`. Assume the base case is `T(1)=1`, then `T(n)` is `sum of S(i) for i = 0 to n-1`.

Answer (score -3):

`T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n/2)+n` is the same as `T(n)=T(n)+T(n/2)+n` since we are solving for extremely large values of n. `T(n)=T(n)+T(n/2)+n` can only be true if  `T(n/2) + n = 0`. That means `T(n) = T(n) + 0 ~= O(n)`